# Getting shell script error - expr: syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, docker, shell

I have a shell script that deletes files in directories that are older than 3 days, but I keep getting the error as posted in the title; `expr: syntax error`, how can I resolve this?

this is the whole script

cleanup.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

avg_video_path=/app/avgVideo/*
videos_path=/app/videos/*
logs_path=/app/logs/*

items_deleted=`expr $items_deleted + $(find $avg_video_path -mtime +2 | wc -l)`
items_deleted=`expr $items_deleted + $(find $videos_path -mtime +2 | wc -l)`
items_deleted=`expr $items_deleted + $(find $logs_path -mtime +2 | wc -l)`

echo "Items to delete: $items_deleted"

if [ $items_deleted -ge 1 ]
then
    find $avg_video_path -mtime +2 -prune -exec rm -rf {} \; # Deletes files & folders that are 7 days or older
    find $videos_path -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;  # Deletes videos that are 7 days or older
    find $logs_path -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;  # Delete logs that are 7 days or older
    echo "Items deleted successfully!"
else
    echo "No items to delete"
fi
```

This script is run every 24 hours, my setup below is how I'm making this happen -

cron_alt.py

```
import time, datetime, subprocess

# 24hrs
SLEEP_TIME = 86400

while True:
    print(f"Current time - {datetime.datetime.now()}; Running cleanup.sh!")
    subprocess.call(['sh', './cleanup.sh'])
    time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.8.16-alpine3.18

RUN apk update && apk add bash

COPY ./cron-alt.py .
COPY ./cleanup.sh .

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN chmod 655 ./cleanup.sh

CMD ["python", "cron-alt.py"]
```

Any help on how I could resolve this issue would be appreciated, thanks